# Does Cassandra select * randomize start node?

Tags: cassandra

If I have a query:

```
select * from table_name where lucene = ... limit 10
(with partition key paging here);
```

Does Cassandra always begin returning results from the same start node?

I'm curious because if I have a service that pages all records from a table table, I'd worry that if I have millions of consumers, they would all start  out by attacking the same node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Cassandra always begin returning results from the same start node?

I think Cassandra start by querying node in the order of their token range so yes it will start querying the same node and moving to other nodes following the ranges of tokens.

> if I have a service that pages **all records from a table** table, I'd worry that if I have **millions of consumers**, they would all start out by attacking the same node.

1. querying the whole table, even using paging, is doing a **full cluster scan**. Apart from **analytics** use-cases, there is absolutely no reason to do such a thing
2. having **millions of consumers** doing a full cluster scan is the worst design ever

Comment: Sorry I should have added it's a paged select * with a custom secondary index.

select * from table_name where lucene = ...

That shouldn't be a full cluster scan, right?

Comment: Also, I don't think if you limit the token ranges (paging), that it would be a full cluster scan for select * from table_name.

Comment: **just** using the lucene secondary index (I guess you're talking about Stratio index) will probably scan all nodes in the cluster unless you set a LIMIT clause OR you provide a partition key OR you restrict with `WHERE token(pk) >= xxx AND token(pk) <= yyy`

Comment: Correct.  Alright, that answers the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Querying by a secondary index will not cause a full table scan, their whole purpose is to allow efficient queries on columns that are not the partition or cluster keys.  However, they are not without pitfalls:  https://pantheon.io/blog/cassandra-scale-problem-secondary-indexes